# Replacing an entry in an ASCII file

Tags: bash, awk, ascii

I'm trying to go in and replace a set of values on an ASCII file. The file has only 2 lines. The first a Header and the second contains the info to modify like this:

```
INFO WAT LAKE
0.002  0.003  0.123
```

The values are separated by tabulators and I want to change each value separately, starting with `0.002` for `0.534`, so far I've tried to do it using sed or awk but being unable to do so. I appreciate the help!

Comment: You could try `sed 's/0.002/0.534/'` on your file. If supported you could use the `-i` (in place change) option or store to a temporary filename and rename to the original filename. If that does not help, please add example input  together with the desired output and explain the problem.

Comment: Do you want to change every occurrence of `0.002` for `0.534` or just those in column 1?

Comment: Your question and requirements are very unclear. Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in `gawk`:

```
gawk '{if (NR==2){ print "0.543", $2, $3 } else print }' your_file
```

If you have values for the other fields as well, fill them in instead of `$2`, `$3`.